# SDL2 focus lost = massive gain in FPS

Tags: c++, sdl, game-loop

Whenever I lose focus from my game window, I go from ~60FPS to 6000+, then when the window gains focus again, I go back to around 60 frames per second. And yes, this happens every time I run my game, including Release mode.

Here is an example log output from my game:

```
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:42.355] Window Gained Focus!
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:45.365] Frames Per Second: 60.0439
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:45.365] Frame Counter: 60
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:46.365] Frames Per Second: 60.0324
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:46.365] Frame Counter: 60
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:47.381] Frames Per Second: 59.4341
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:47.382] Frame Counter: 58
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:49.669] Window Lost Focus!
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:50.383] Frames Per Second: 1240.02
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:50.383] Frame Counter: 9561
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:51.384] Frames Per Second: 1839.02
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:51.384] Frame Counter: 6662
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:52.77] Window Gained Focus!
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:52.400] Frames Per Second: 1656.77
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:52.400] Frame Counter: 34
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:53.400] Frames Per Second: 1512.46
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:53.400] Frame Counter: 60
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:54.401] Frames Per Second: 1391.89
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:54.402] Frame Counter: 60
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:55.402] Frames Per Second: 1289.78
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:55.402] Frame Counter: 58
[INFO] [10/01/2013 22:37:55.876] Quitting with error code: 0
```

The frame counter is just a simple integer that I increment every loop in the game, and then reset (and print it out) every second. [Here](https://github.com/miguelishawt/Pine-Game-Framework/blob/master/pine/GameLoop.h) is the implementation of my game loop, (inside the run() function), based off of [this](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) article.

Is this a problem with my loop, or is this a problem with SDL? I'm not sure why my frame rate is rocketing up.

Comment: Is your update function paired with the render function? Does it get called less if you focus away?

Comment: @VaughanHilts My update function gets called ~100 times per frame, regardless of the game's FPS (and regardless of losing focus). However, my drawing is done per-frame, therefore it is getting called 6000+ (when I lose focus) times per second. (I don't actually have any rendering code being called though)

Comment: The loop here is fairly irrelevant - all the real work, including any SDL specific stuff, is being done in functions we can't see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

60 fps in focus mode is very suspicious, it must be vsync.

Why vsync is turned off when the app loses focus is not a question I can answer though.

Comment: Sure seems like it, I stop flipping opengl's buffer in my render function and the FPS was at 13000+ even when focused.